# deselecting button from another view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

**UPDATED**

viewcontroller A goes to B and then comes back to A. I have a UIButton, in each of the cells of a UItableview in viewcontrollerA. When you click the button, the button highlights and goes to viewcontrollerB. I want the buttons to deselect when you go back to viewcontrollerA. 
The highlighting of the buttons work great is the deselecting that is the issue.

in cellforrowatindexpath, i have this:

```
        if(indexPath.row==selectedbuttonindex)
        {
            addpeople.selected=YES;
        }
        else
        {
            addpeople.selected=NO;
        }

            UIImage *buttonImageNormal =[UIImage imageNamed:@"addtochatNormal.png"];
                 UIImage *buttonImageSelected =[UIImage imageNamed:@"addtochatSelected.png"];
           [addpeople addTarget:self action:@selector(addpeopletoChat:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


                [addpeople setBackgroundImage:buttonImageSelected     forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


                 [addpeople setBackgroundImage:buttonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                  [addpeople setBackgroundImage:buttonImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];

                  addpeople.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 51, 44);

                  [cell.contentView addSubview:addpeople];
```

I considered the answers below and here is my updated code, still not working though:

the selecting of the buttons and changing of view controllers is achieved with the following method:

```
  -(void) addpeopletoChat : (UIButton*)button{



       UITableViewCell *cell_ = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
       NSIndexPath *index_Path = [topictableView indexPathForCell:cell_];
       NSLog(@"%@", index_Path);
   selectedbuttonindex=index_Path.row;
  [topictableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:index_Path]    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   countaddpeople=countaddpeople+1;

  addpeopletochatViewController* viewcontrollerB = [[addpeopletochatViewController alloc]    init];
   viewcontrollerB.viewcontrollerA=self;

   [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight];//changes view to viewcontroller B


  }
```

this was supposed to deselect it

```
  -(void) somefuction{

  NSLog(@"%d", selectedbuttonindex);
   NSUInteger indexArr[] = {0,selectedbuttonindex};
   NSIndexPath *index_Path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexArr length:2];
   selectedbuttonindex=-1;
   NSLog(@"%@" @"%@", @"hi", index_Path);

   [topictableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:index_Path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

   }
```

in the h file of viewcontroller B i have:

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import "officerTopicsViewController.h"

  @class officerTopicsViewController;
  @interface addpeopletochatViewController : UIViewController{


  }
  @property (nonatomic,retain) officerTopicsViewController *viewcontrollerA;

  @end
```

and in its m file i have:

```
 -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
  {

 [viewcontrollerA somefunction];


  }
```

But it stills doesn't work though, this time somefunction doesn't even get called as the NSlogs don't show up like it did the first time.

Regards

Comment: Try this method somefuction in viewWillAppear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show either the A->B or B->A transition code, so I'm assuming from A you're pushing B and from B you're just "going back" to A.  In Viewcontroller B you're creating a new instance of viewcontroller A and calling somefunction, which has nothing to do with your existing viewcontroller A which is the one that pushed your instance of viewcontroller B.  What you need to do instead is to pass your instance of viewcontroller A as a property of viewcontroller B, and call somefunction on that saved viewcontroller A.     Alternatively, you could just reset selectedbuttonindex to -1 in viewcontrollerA's viewWillAppear method.

For example, when creating and pushing ViewControllerB:

```
...
viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
[viewControllerB setViewControllerA: self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
...
```

and in ViewControllerB you then have:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [myViewControllerA somefuction];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Cant try it right now but it seems right. i tried the view will appear method, but that doesn't work because of the way i handle my view controllers.

Comment: You need to implement the method in viewControllerB.   It is quite simple to verify this as working in the debugger.   If you implement it as a property in viewControllerB then you'd write viewControllerB.myViewControllerA = self;

Comment: is viewDidDisappear getting called?

Comment: that you, it worked it was because i prefered using  [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight]; but i after compromising, it worked perfectly when i used pushviewcontroller. Thank

Comment: It may work with slidingViewController and just using a different trigger than viewControllerB's viewDidDisappear.   You just need to determine what gets called when you go back from B to A and put the call to A's somefunction there.   Glad it's working for you though now.